# Multiline regex for ctags

Tags: regex, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I have some Java code

```
@Subscribe
public void catchEvent(SomeEvent
```

And I want to match it with something like this in my ~/.ctags

```
--langdef=javaspring
--langmap=javaspring:.java
--regex-javaspring=/@Subscribe(\s)*([a-z ]+)\s([a-zA-Z]*)\(([a-zA-Z]*)/\3-\4/
```

This should generate something like "catchEvent-SomeEvent" but it does not. If I remove the newline between @Subscribe and public void it gets it.

```
@Subscribe public void catchEvent(SomeEvent

rm -rf tags && ctags -R . && cat tags|grep Subs
catchEvent-SomeEvent    PathToMyFile.java    /^@Subscribe public void catchEvent(SomeEvent event) {$/;"      r
```

I even tried using begin/end of line like this

```
--regex-javaspring=/^\s*@Subscribe[a-z \s]+\s([a-zA-Z]+)\(([a-zA-Z]+).*$/@Subscribe \1 \2*/
```

Do you have any idea if I can do this with the current ctag implementation. Am I doing something wrong or ctags does not support multi-line regex now.

Thank you!

Comment: Some regex dialects use \\_s to mean white space including newlines, while \s does not include newlines.  I don't know if this will work, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 2):

For Universal Ctags you can use the `--mline-regex-<LANG>` feature with the `{mgroup=1}` option:

```
--mline-regex-javaspring=/^\s*@Subscribe[a-z \s]+\s([a-zA-Z]+)\(([a-zA-Z]+).*$/@Subscribe \1 \2*/{mgroup=1}
```

The `mgroup` option is necessary to tell Ctags how to determine the line number of the expression.